# How do I install scripy into Python?

Tags: python, pip, spss, pls

I am trying to install scripy into python using the administrator command on windows 10.  the error message i get is:

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.**
```

How can I fix this?

I have tried different versions of python (3.12, 3.9 and 3.8), each version gives the same error message.

My ultimate goal is to download `numpy` (which has been successfully downloaded) and `scripy` (unsuccessful) to use in SPSS to do partial least squares regression.

I followed [the IBM manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-enable-partial-least-squares-regression-pls-ibm-spss-statistics-27) on how to set up the PLS extension in SPSS.

EVERYTHING works, except that `scripy` does not want to install.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your link: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-enable-partial-least-squares-regression-pls-ibm-spss-statistics-27. They clearly made a spelling mistake in the installation command.

The library you want to install is `SciPy` not `scripy`. While `SciPy` is used to solve scientific and mathematical problems, `scripy` is used for shell scripting with python. Those two are very different libraries. Besides, `scripy` doesn't support windows, hence the error you're facing.

You need to install `SciPy` using the following command:

```
pip install SciPy
```

This will install the latest `scipy` on your system.

Comment: I don't know too much about this particular library, but I also figured out that there's no `setup.py` file in this library, on link that I've provided. Also, might be a stupid question, but, shouldn't he be able to install `Scripy` manually by downloading package and then setting it up in Python environment (even if the Windows is platform that he's using)?

Comment: nah, it's not built for Windows. also, I checked the OP's IBM link, they clearly made a spelling mistake. they are showing that they are installing `scipy` but they provided the command for `scripy`, which is clearly a mistake. And the analysis he is trying to do also needs `scipy` not `scripy`.

Comment: on a different note, the `scripy` library was built for `python2.6`, for the purpose it was built back then serves no purpose now. now, you can use the `subprocess` or `os` module easily to do shell scripting from Python. That's why probably it's not maintained anymore.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense, as I said I just saw it's built in 2010, so I was just looking at this problem as general problem with installing libraries, anyways, obviously you're more knowledgeable of it usage means etc., so I guess my answer would be missguiding therefore I deleted it.